# How to get an exact representation of floats during `DataFrame.to_json`?

Tags: python, json, pandas, floating-point

I observed the following behavior with [`DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[eval(f'1.12345e-{i}') for i in range(8, 20)]])
>>> df
             0             1             2             3             4             5             6             7             8             9             10            11
0  1.123450e-08  1.123450e-09  1.123450e-10  1.123450e-11  1.123450e-12  1.123450e-13  1.123450e-14  1.123450e-15  1.123450e-16  1.123450e-17  1.123450e-18  1.123450e-19
>>> print(df.to_json(indent=2, orient='index'))
{
  "0":{
    "0":0.0000000112,
    "1":0.0000000011,
    "2":0.0000000001,
    "3":0.0,
    "4":0.0,
    "5":0.0,
    "6":0.0,
    "7":0.0,
    "8":1.12345e-16,
    "9":1.12345e-17,
    "10":1.12345e-18,
    "11":1.12345e-19
  }
}
```

So all numbers down to `1e-16` seem to be rounded to 10 decimal places (in agreement with the default value for `double_precision`) but all smaller values are represented exactly. Why is this the case and how can I turn off decimal rounding for the larger values too (i.e. using scientific notation instead)?

---

```py
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.1'
```

---

For reference, the standard library's [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) doesn't do this:

```py
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps([eval(f'1.12345e-{i}') for i in range(8, 20)], indent=2))
[
  1.12345e-08,
  1.12345e-09,
  1.12345e-10,
  1.12345e-11,
  1.12345e-12,
  1.12345e-13,
  1.12345e-14,
  1.12345e-15,
  1.12345e-16,
  1.12345e-17,
  1.12345e-18,
  1.12345e-19
]
```

Comment: a_guest, you can try as its precision problem as i said earlier, `print(df.to_json(indent=2, orient='records', double_precision=15))` , all the number down to 10 are using precision value that's 10 by default and where we see like `3":0.0` these are havig all 0's upto precision point thus wrapping up them to `3":0.0` because there no literal nums like 1,2...etc

Comment: @KarnKumar I don't understand what you mean; `double_precision=15` is the max. precision allowed by `to_json` but it still truncates the example data (e.g. `"7":0.000000000000001`). I want to prevent this and get an exact floating point representation for all numbers (like the standard library `json` module does it).

Comment: Please see the updated answer, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on achieving this with [pd.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), but we can use [pd.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and [pd.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.json.read_json.html) to achieve a full precision json representation from a pandas dataframe.

```
json_df = json.dumps(df.to_dict('index'), indent=2)
>>> print(json_df)
{
  "0": {
    "0": 1.12345e-08,
    "1": 1.12345e-09,
    "2": 1.12345e-10,
    "3": 1.12345e-11,
    "4": 1.12345e-12,
    "5": 1.12345e-13,
    "6": 1.12345e-14,
    "7": 1.12345e-15,
    "8": 1.12345e-16,
    "9": 1.12345e-17,
    "10": 1.12345e-18,
    "11": 1.12345e-19
  }
}
```

To read it back in, we can then do:

```
>>> pd.read_json(json_df, orient='index')
             0             1             2   ...            9             10            11
0  1.123450e-08  1.123450e-09  1.123450e-10  ...  1.123450e-17  1.123450e-18  1.123450e-19

[1 rows x 12 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

It refers to `/pandas/io/json/_json.py` [codebase](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/json/_json.py), by default the `precision` integer is upto `10`, please see the below from the codebase..

```
def to_json(
    path_or_buf,
    obj,
    orient: Optional[str] = None,
    date_format: str = "epoch",
    double_precision: int = 10,
    force_ascii: bool = True,
    date_unit: str = "ms",
    default_handler: Optional[Callable[[Any], JSONSerializable]] = None,
    lines: bool = False,
    compression: Optional[str] = "infer",
    index: bool = True,
    indent: int = 0,
```

If you apply max precision then, you will be getting below..

```
>>> print(df.to_json(indent=2, orient='records', double_precision=15))
[
  {
    "0":0.0000000112345,
    "1":0.00000000112345,
    "2":0.000000000112345,
    "3":0.000000000011234,
    "4":0.000000000001123,
    "5":0.000000000000112,
    "6":0.000000000000011,
    "7":0.000000000000001,
    "8":1.12345e-16,
    "9":1.12345e-17,
    "10":1.12345e-18,
    "11":1.12345e-19,
    "12":1.12345e-20,
    "13":1.12345e-21,
    "14":1.12345e-22,
    "15":1.12345e-23,
    "16":1.12345e-24,
    "17":1.12345e-25,
    "18":1.12345e-26,
    "19":1.12345e-27,
    "20":1.12345e-28,
    "21":1.12345e-29,
    "22":1.12345e-30,
    "23":1.12345e-31,
    "24":1.12345e-32,
    "25":1.12345e-33,
    "26":1.12345e-34,
    "27":1.12345e-35,
    "28":1.12345e-36,
    "29":1.12345e-37,
    "30":1.12345e-38,
    "31":1.12345e-39
  }
]
```

Note: you will get value error if you use `precision` more than 15.

```
ValueError: Invalid value '20' for option 'double_precision', max is '15'
```

So, in a sense this is not same as `json.dumps`.

Comment: My question is about the conversion to JSON. The problem that I have is that this conversion results in loss of data (namely rounding values > 1e-16 to max. 15 decimal places). My question is how I can solve this and get an exact representation for all values (e.g. scientific notation, but not necessarily).

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame.to_json` uses internal library `pandas._libs.json` and not a standard `json` module. This explains the difference in behavior. The former "normalizes" the numbers internally and does not expose API to control it. As a result, you have following options:

Either convert to dictionary and dump using standard `json` library (as mentioned earlier):

```
>>> print(json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records'), indent=2))

[
  {
    "0": 1.12345e-08,
    "1": 1.12345e-09,
    "2": 1.12345e-10,
    "3": 1.12345e-11,
    "4": 1.12345e-12,
    "5": 1.12345e-13,
    "6": 1.12345e-14,
    "7": 1.12345e-15,
    "8": 1.12345e-16,
    "9": 1.12345e-17,
    "10": 1.12345e-18,
    "11": 1.12345e-19
  }
]
```

This is perfectly legitimate solution.

You can use CSV format instead of JSON and specify desired floating point format:

```
>>> print(df.to_csv(float_format='%.10e', index=False))

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
1.1234500000e-08,1.1234500000e-09,1.1234500000e-10,1.1234500000e-11,1.1234500000e-12,1.1234500000e-13,1.1234500000e-14,1.1234500000e-15,1.1234500000e-16,1.1234500000e-17,1.1234500000e-18,1.1234500000e-19
```

Another option is to convert values to string before the "normalization" kicks in:

```
>>> print(df.astype(str).to_json(indent=2, orient='index'))

{
  "0":{
    "0":"1.12345e-08",
    "1":"1.12345e-09",
    "2":"1.12345e-10",
    "3":"1.12345e-11",
    "4":"1.12345e-12",
    "5":"1.12345e-13",
    "6":"1.12345e-14",
    "7":"1.12345e-15",
    "8":"1.12345e-16",
    "9":"1.12345e-17",
    "10":"1.12345e-18",
    "11":"1.12345e-19"
  }
}
```

The conversion to string will require special attention when reading back the JSON.

And finally, if you need the exact values, just use binary format such as `parquet` or `pickle`.

Comment: is there a way to just convert all the individual tags (even within nested arrays) to string without converting the outer array (or any array itself) to string?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot get an "exact floating point representation" of your numbers, as they do not have an exact binary representation. E.g. *decimal* 1.2345e-8 can be represented **exactly** in 5 decimal digits (plus exponent) but when converted to binary, it's a repeating fraction so cannot be represented exactly in a finite number of binary digits. So there will inevitably be a rounding error. You can see this by printing to over full precision:

```py
>>> [print(f'{eval(f"1.12345e-{i}"):.17e}') for i in range(8,20)]
1.12345000000000004e-08
1.12345000000000009e-09
1.12345000000000001e-10
1.12344999999999994e-11
1.12345000000000002e-12
1.12345000000000000e-13
1.12345000000000006e-14
1.12344999999999994e-15
1.12345000000000004e-16
1.12344999999999998e-17
1.12344999999999998e-18
1.12345000000000008e-19
```

That aside, I guess your problem is the pandas `to_json` implementation. What seems to be happening is that the precision (specified by `double_precision`) is a fixed number of *decimal places* (NOT *significant figures*), and it's just ignored if the value is lower than 1e-15.

I would view this as a bug, since any number between 1e-10 (the default value of `double_precision`) and 1e-15 will be completely lost - you'll just get zero.

Even if you use `double_precision=15` you are getting increasingly inaccurate serialised values as you approach the limit, until suddenly they become more accurate again, so I'd suggest that only having the option of a fixed number of decimal places, which *might* be ignored, is questionable and there should at the very least be an option to serialise to a fixed number of significant figures, perhaps even by default to be consistent with the json module.

I would raise both of these as issues with the pandas developers.

As for a quick solution, go with @maneblusser's suggestion: use `to_dict` then `json.dumps`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this problem. I am aware of the limitations of floating point math, hence I wrote "exact representation of *floats*" whereby I referred to `float` objects; by *exact representation* I mean that the following should hold: `x == float(repr(x))` where `repr` stands for pandas' way of representing floats through `to_json`.